# El middleware auth siempre me retorna al Login

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

Buen dia,

Tengo un view que restingí con middleware('auth'), hasta que se autentique, sin embargo siempre me retorna al login.

La autenticación del login funciona bien, sin el middleware, si me redigire al view correctamente, validando las credenciales con Auth::attemp.
Ademas aclaro que trabajo con un GUARD llamado 'usuario'

Alguna recomendación o solucion que me sugieran por favor.

```
//Controller login

public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    
    $email = request('email');   
    $password = request('password');

    
    if (Auth::guard('usuario')->attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
        
        $id = Auth::guard('usuario')->user()->Id_usuarios;
        session(['idUser' =>  $id]);

        return  redirect('discover');        

    }else{
        Session::flash('warning','Mensaje de sesion informativo');  
        return  redirect('login');
    }
    

}
```

---

```
//Controler Cuenta (view restringido)

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth:usuario');
}
```